# Someone knows why I can not install steam on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, steam

I'm fresh here, I'm trying to install the steam package on Ubuntu 16.04 but it says that " this software comes from a 3rd party and may contain no-free components. " and simply don't give me a solution. Any help is welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The solution would be not using Steam because Steam happens to be non-free software. But you probably don't care about that.

It's just a warning, not an error message. You can just go ahead and hit the "install" button.

Alternatively, execute

```
sudo dpkg -i steam.deb
```

Where `steam.deb` is the package you downloaded. For example:

```
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/steam.deb
```

Comment: Thank you, however about the steam does not be free software If you look at the steam website it incentives you to use steam. Anyway, I thank you very much.

Comment: "Free software" doesn't mean you don't have to pay to use it. It means you have the freedom to study, change, redistribute, and redistribute your changes in whatever way you wish. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software Steam does not grant you those freedoms. Steam is [proprietary software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proprietary_software), meaning that someone (Valve Corporation) retains intellectual property rights and uses them to restrict people in their freedoms to do the above-mentioned. Steam is gratis, not free. Btw.: There is that check mark on the left to accept an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation I have success by trying your first post. By the way, it is working very well, even though it be a non-free  software as you have mentioned. Thank you.